# How to fix number of threads in gdb run of an OpenMP program

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, openmp

I am trying to debug an OpenMP C++ program with gdb on a Mac OSX machine.  (OK, using "ggdb" technically.)  No matter what I set OMP_NUM_THREADS to, gdb tries to run the code on 8 threads.  Why is this?  Is there a way for me to tell it myself the number of threads the code will run on?

Comment: Show us the code, at least how parallel section is defined. The number of threads can be set many ways and some of them have higher priority than `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Comment: What is the number of threads without using gdb?

Comment: @ks1322  Running without a debugger, the number of threads is whatever I set OMP_NUM_THREADS to.  For right now, I want to run it on just two.

Comment: How do you set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` when run within debugger? And how many cores / hardware threads is on your machine?

Comment: @DanielLangr  Well, I guess I'm showing my ignorance, but I set it just before I start up the debugger.  Am I supposed to do it within the debugger?  Don't know how.

Comment: Try `(gdb) set environment OMP_NUM_THREADS 2` before running the program in gdb.

Comment: @ks1322  OK, that did it!  Thank you.  Will be happy to hit the "accept" button if you want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, I guess I'm showing my ignorance, but I set it just before I
>   start up the debugger. Am I supposed to do it within the debugger?

You should set environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` inside gdb:

```
(gdb) set environment OMP_NUM_THREADS 2
```

See also builtin help:

```
(gdb) help set environment 
Set environment variable value to give the program.
Arguments are VAR VALUE where VAR is variable name and VALUE is value.
VALUES of environment variables are uninterpreted strings.
This does not affect the program until the next "run" command.
```